# Unable to launch application with instruments using Xcode 4

Tags: instruments, xcode4

I created a scheme for my device as specified in the documentation for Xcode 4. Under profile, I selected, "Ask on launch", but instruments never pops up.

I tried selecting Leaks, but this did not launch either. I also tried leaving instruments open before running but still no dice.

Anyone having similar issues? This is not a beta release of xcode 4.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your question right.. but are u saying that you are not able to open instruments? or after opening instruments, you are not able to open leaks?

Comment: I am able to open instruments and leaks separately from xcode and attach it to the application in the simulator. I cannot attach it to the device while debugging. I usually select run with performance tool from the menu to do this in Xcode 3. Xcode 4 uses "scheme's" with settings for it. They are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems if you click the "Play" button to the left and select the wrench icon it asks you which instrument to run with. Appropriate scheme as described in the original question is still required.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this totally addresses your question, but I was wondering about this myself and accidentally discovered that hitting command-i in Xcode 4 seems to build the current project, open Instruments, and allow you to select the desired Instruments tool. I'm not quite sure how schemes factor into this yet, but it at least seems to save a step or two.